# Validating t-test results using Python scipy

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I have simple Python function:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_1samp

def tTest( expectedMean, sampleSet, alpha=0.05 ):
    # T-value and P-value
    tv, pv = ttest_1samp(sampleSet, expectedMean)
    print(tv,pv)
    return pv >= alpha

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Expected mean is 10
    print tTest(10.0, [99, 99, 22, 77, 99, 55, 44, 33, 20, 9999, 99, 99, 99])
```

My expectation is that t-test should fail for this sample, as it is nowhere near the expected population mean of 10. However, program produces result:

```
(1.0790344826428238, 0.3017839504736506)
True
```

I.e. the p-value is ~30% which is too high to reject the hypothesis. I am not very knowledgeable about the maths behind t-test but I don't understand how this result can be correct. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you intentionally include the value `9999` in your sample, or did you mean for that to be `99, 99`?

Comment: I intentionally put in some outliers... Am I breaking something because my sample isn't really normally distributed?

Comment: As @MiguelSantos points out in the answer below, that large value results in your sample having a large variance, which gives a low t-statistic, and therefore a high p value.

Comment: Your standard deviation for that sample is 2753.88 the mean is 834.16 (both rounded) 10.0 is within 1 standard deviation form the mean of your population. Hence you can not reject null hypothesis. Extremely simplified version.

Comment: Interesting... I did a simple calculation on paper. Indeed, t-value `tv = (mean-expectedMean)/sqrt(var/n)` is `~1.123` which is lower than t-value even for alpha of `10%` on student's distribution with 12 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed the test using R just to check if the results are the same and they are:

```
t.test(x=c(99, 99, 22, 77, 99, 55, 44, 33, 20, 9999, 99, 99, 99), alternative = "two.sided", 
mu = 10, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95)

data:  c(99, 99, 22, 77, 99, 55, 44, 33, 20, 9999, 99, 99, 99)
t = 1.079, df = 12, p-value = 0.3018
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 10
95 percent confidence interval:
-829.9978 2498.3055
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 834.1538
```

You can see that the p-value is 0.3.
This is a really interesting problem, I have a lot of issues with Hypothesis testing. First of all the sample size influences a lot, if u have a big sample size, lets say 5000 values, minor deviations from the expected value that you are testing will influence a lot the p-value, and so you will reject the null hypothesis most of the times, having small samples does the opposite.
And what is happening here is that you have a high variance in the data.

If you try to replace your data from `[99, 99, 22, 77, 99, 55, 44, 33, 20, 9999, 99, 99, 99]`

To
`[99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 99, 99, 99, 99, 100, 99, 100, 100]`

So it has a really small variance, your p-value will be a lot smaller, even tho the mean of this one is probably closer to 10.

Comment: So is the conclusion here that the sample size is simply too small to conduct a meaningful t-test?

Comment: The sample size is too small and the variance is too big both of those are pushing the p-value up. The higher the variance in your data the higher the sample size you want to have to be able to perform a good test